# CURL Post frontend security

Tags: php, security, curl

Is it safe to use php curl posting to receive data from external site to frontend?

I must send with the curl post htaccess login details to get the data. Can those login details be hacked or seen from client side (ie. when client loading page where curl triggered?

What I know this far, its just server to server post so client can't see the details posted with curl (its done with php)?

Comment: For so far, users can't see PHP sources on the frontend, they also can't see any CURL requests (If I'm right). If you are not sure, you can send encrypted data between the two servers (If possible).